# rautomation - in RubyMine with jRuby - getting error

Tags: cucumber, rautomation

I was looking for automating windows applications and was asked to explore with rautomation, which I just started using it.

Now, after going thru' documentation on github and Jarmo's few blogs, I am posting a very simple problem here and I am sure I am doing something very basic wrongly.

Here is my code -

```
>> require "rubygems"
=> true
>> require "rautomation"
=> true
>> @window = RAutomation::Window.new :title => "System Volume (C:)"
RuntimeError: unsupported platform for RAutomation: java
    from C:/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rautomation-0.6.3/lib/rautomation/adapter/helper.rb:16:in `default_adapter'
    from C:/jruby-1.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rautomation-0.6.3/lib/rautomation/window.rb:65:in `initialize'
    from (irb):10:in `new'
    from (irb):10
```

So, question is - what am I doing wrong?
Here, I am trying to get handle on windows explorer.

Done - 
Done. The problem is with Jruby usage. If I use (plain) ruby with rubymine then I don't get any problem.
Stackoverflow won't allow me to close my question until I have 100 reputation.

Comment: Done - Done. The problem is with Jruby usage. If I use (plain) ruby with rubymine then I don't get any problem. Stackoverflow won't allow me to close my question until I have 100 reputation.

Comment: You do not need to close the question. Post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.. It won't allow me to answer my own question until I have 100 reputation... So, I added it as comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because RAutomation was determining compatibility from the **RUBY_PLATFORM**. Next version will use OS Environment variable instead:
https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/commit/dd825b04aab6d90cfedf385a620095c17da92644

But, you could also use it with JRuby (it's untested though, but it **should** work) right now by specifying the adapter itself so that #default_adapter method won't be executed. You can do that in two ways:

1) Specify the adapter to the Window.new method:

```
RAutomation::Window.new(:title => //, :adapter => :win_ffi)
```

2) Specify the adapter in the environment variable:

```
set RAUTOMATION_ADAPTER=win_ffi
```